# Как загрузить аватар в базу данных в формате base_64 и загрузить это в profile.php

Tags: php, сервер

signup.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    $msg = isset($_SESSION['msg']) ? $_SESSION['msg'] : '';

    if (preg_match('/[^\p{Latin}]/u', $login)) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Логин содержит кириллицу. Напишите латинскими буквами';
        header('Location ../register.php');
    } else {
        if (preg_match('/[^\p{Latin}]/u', $password)) {
            $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Пароль содержит кириллицу. Напишите латинскими буквами';
            header('Location: ../register.php');
        } else {
            if ($password === $password2) {
                $path = 'uploads/' . time() . $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
                if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], '../' . $path)) {
                    
                    $msg = 'Ошибка при загрузке аватара';
                    header('Location: ../register.php');
                    
                }

                $query = "SELECT `avatar` FROM `zprodaccountservices` WHERE `zprodaccountservices`.`login` = ?";
                $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
                $stmt->execute();
                
                if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                    $avatar = $row['avatar'];
                
                    if (!is_null($avatar)) {
                        $imageData = base64_decode($avatar);
                        $image = imagecreatefromstring($imageData);
                
                            // Do something with the image
                            // For example, save it to a file
                        imagepng($image, $path);
                            
                            // Remember to free memory allocated for the image
                        imagedestroy($image);
                    
                    }
                    else {
                        $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Ошибка загрузки аватара';
                        header('Location: ../register.php');
                    }
                }

            $check_login = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `zprodaccountservices` WHERE `login` = '$login'");
            if (mysqli_num_rows($check_login) > 0) {
                $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Данный логин уже существует, введите другой!';
                header('Location: ../index.php');
            } else {
                
                $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `zprodaccountservices` (`id`, `login`, `email`, `avatar`, `password`, `password2`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $login, $email, $image, $password, $password2);
                $stmt->execute();
                if (!$stmt->execute()) {
                    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " . $stmt->error;
                    header('Location: ../register.php');
                }
                $stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO `zepics` (`user_id`, `login`, `cb5f07b1bb794a5e898656d411fc0467`, `639ec7bf2a974488a15aa864e877479d`, `cc2bfaf5ff3d424494e5fb2dd99e50fc`, `bdf627f939c9498887f39851e7615ca7`) VALUES (NULL, ?, 'false', 'false', 'false', 'false')");
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
                $stmt->execute();
                header('Location: ../index.php');
            }
        } else {
            $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Пароли не совпадают!';
            header('Location: ../register.php');
        }
        }
        }
        
        

    

        

?>
```

profile.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['user']) {
        header('Location: /');
    }
    include 'vendor/signup.php';
    $loginconfirm = $_SESSION['user']['login'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Z. PROD >> Профиль <?= $_SESSION['user']['login'] ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/profile-style.css">
    <script src="buttonRedirect.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="profile-box">
            <h2>Z. Prod</h2>
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . <?= $avatar ?> . '" class="profile-pic">
            <div class="main-info">
                <p class="title"><?= $_SESSION['user']['title'] ?></p>
                <h3 class="login"><?= $_SESSION['user']['login'] ?></h3>
                
            </div>
            <button type="button" onclick="accountdelete()">Удалить аккаунт</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="logout()">Выход</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="pass()">Сменить пароль</button>
            <div class="profile-bottom">
            <p>Ваш ID: <?= $_SESSION['user']['id'] ?></p>
            <p>Ваша почта: <?= $_SESSION['user']['email'] ?></p>
            </div>     
        </div>
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

при попытке вывести
 . '" class="profile-pic">
выводит значок повреждённого изображения.

Я пробовал спрашивать у AI. Помогало исправлять проблемы, но появлялись проблемы одни за другой. В итоге достиг того, что проблемы пропали, а аватарка не грузит

Comment: Так проблема с внесением в БД или выводом информации?

Comment: проблема и с тем, и тем. В базе данных в столбце `avatar` ничего нет. А изображение отображает в profile.php в качестве повреждённого

Comment: во-первых возьмите отладчик и пройдитесь по коду PHP и проследите что не так... (об отладке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701146/191482)  . как минимум возможно что-то не так с переменной `$image` возможно выше в коде не попадает в условия для его формирования......во-вторых включите сообщения об ошибках  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701145/191482   ..возможно что-то они скажут....в-третьих - примера JS, который отправляет данные на сервер тут не представлено..и вообще той формы....возможно сама отправка сделана коряво...опять же надо  смотреть в отладку PHP и в консоль разработчика для JS

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. По поводу JS, у меня его почти нет. Он нужен только для перехода по html кнопкам. Весь бэкэнд сделан на php

Comment: и кстати в коде нет base64_encode , а значит что обработка происходит только случая, если аватар есть в БД... и если есть - то почему-то декодированная версия записывается в $image...... код очень странный, видимо сгенерированный..... проще нормально адекватно заново написать имхо.....

Comment: Где в коде `profile.php` ваш `$avatar` объявлен? Видимо переменная должна содержать `$avatar = $row['avatar'];` из БД, хотя это не указано, как и то, что она хотя бы из сессии берётся...